# Debug google app engine project line by line

Tags: google-app-engine

Could anyone please recommend an easy to set up debugger for a google app engine project I'm working on?

Ideally, I want to click a html button on a particular page, and then then see step by step the code which is executed, function by function until it errors.  I'm running the appserver locally with

```
 dev_appserver.py . --datastore_path /tmp/data.store
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python, you can use Eclipse with Pydev. It has an excellent debugger and tracer.
Here is a tutorial for starting with Eclipse and Pydev. But you do not need to add the src folder (figure 4.2). http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/

Comment: I'm going to accept but found eclipse a nightmare on mac.  To anyone checking this I recommend using pycharm.